# Failed postgresql service

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I made a fresh postgresql (Ubuntu 16.04). When I type `systemctl` then it returns:
`postgresql@9.5-main.service   loaded failed failed    PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main`. I totally don't know when it is failed.
`psql` command retruns:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

In my whole PC there is not such file as ".s.PGSQL.5432"

Running `systemctl restart postgresql@9.5-main.service` causes `Job for postgresql@9.5-main.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Can somebody explain me what's wrong?

Comment: It's a common issue with `postgres` . Try making sure that domain socket path exist or point to the right file.

Comment: whole postgresql.conf content is left as default. Which variable should I note?

Comment: Please do some research, since it's a common issue you'll get tons of solution on net. I faced the same issue and got away with exiting solution.

Comment: Yes Ive visited hundreds of sites but unfortunately any solutions directly fit to my case.

Comment: Easy. Just look into the PostgreSQL server log.

Comment: It's the same content as systemctl returns